# How do I access an Ubuntu VM on Vmware, without a password

Tags: ssh, vmware-vsphere, ssh-keys, ubuntu-18.04, vmware-vcenter

I have an Ubuntu VM that is running on Vmware, this does not have a root password. Recently I disabled the ssh on this VM, so not able to access it. Is it possible to access this through the Vcenter console with the ssh key? I have tried resetting the password on this using grub, but not able to get into the configuration screen. This are the versions of the components involved.

Guest OS - Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Hypervisor: VMware ESXi, 6.7.0
vSphere Client version 6.7.0.44000

Answer (score 2):

Boot into the single user mode. To do that you press ESC a couple of times when grub appears to stop it. Then edit the boot entry and add the number `1`. Continue the boot process. Ubuntu will start and you will be logged in as root automatically. Repair your system, set new passwords or whatever you need and reboot it again. It will boot into the regular multiuser mode.

I can't provide more details as I'm only on my phone, but the process to boot into single user mode is well documented, user your favorite search engine for details.